# At which point in the thread can the scheduler leave and start another thread?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, scheduler

Let's say I have two threads running and each one has a for loop , is it possible for the scheduler to shift from thread1 to thread2 while thread1 is in the middle of an iteration in the for loop ? So let's say for loop is running the nth iteration and while in the middle of it scheduler schedules the other thread. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is. The scheduler can switch threads any time it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible for the scheduler to shift from thread1 to thread2
>   while thread1 is in the middle of an iteration in the for loop ?

Assuming you are running your program on an operating system that supports [pre-emptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#PREEMPTIVE)(1), yes.  In particular, the operating system's scheduler will have a timer set up that triggers an interrupt once per quantum (where a quantum is typically on the range of 5-10 milliseconds), and when the interrupt routine is called, it will decide whether or not to continue running the current thread or switch to a different thread.  This is what allows the computer to appear to be doing multiple operations at once, even on a single-core CPU.

Note that there were (and probably still are) OS's (such as the [classic Macintosh OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mac_OS)) that did not have pre-emptive multitasking; when writing a program for that OS, you had to be careful to explicitly call [WaitNextEvent](http://everything2.com/title/WaitNextEvent)() every so often, otherwise no other programs would ever be allowed to execute.  This made writing timing-sensitive programs like mp3 players difficult, and also meant that a single poorly-written program could easily freeze up the computer (requiring a power cycle to recover) simply by entering into an infinite loop that didn't include a call to WaitNextEvent().

(1) which is to say, pretty much any modern consumer-facing OS